# Changing readahead value using blockdev command

Tags: linux, block-device, ioctl

I am trying to modify read ahead value using blockdev. When I issue this command 
`blockdev --setra xxx /dev/sda` - it changes the readahead value of the entire partition in that device, which is fine. But when I went to any of the partition in that device and check inode_readahead_blk value under `/sys/fs/ext4` folder, I don't find the same readahead value I changed earlier using blockdev. I am little confused about this. Would any one of you cast some light on this one please?

Answer (score 1):

The read-ahead set by *blockdev(8)* is applied to the **block device** that holds the EXT4 partitions.

The read-ahead setting on an EXT4 file system (as any other EXT4 setting for that matter) is specific to that file system.

So two completely different settings, which just happen to have a similar name: device read-ahead specify how many **512-bytes sector** the kernel should read in advance and cache after a request. EXT4's `inode_readahead_blks` controls the number of **inode blocks** to be read into the cache.